# Getting error while printing a link list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written the following link list append, prepend and print methods for LinkedList:

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
};


class LinkedList {
private:
    Node *header;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
    
public:
    LinkedList() {
        header = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }
    
    int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    
    void append(int data) {
        Node *n = new Node(data);
        
        if (header == NULL) {
            header = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        
        size++;
    }
    
    void prepend(int data) {
        Node *n = new Node(data);
        
        if (header == NULL) {
            header = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else {
            Node *temp = header;
            header = n;
            n->next = temp;
        }
        
        size++;
    }
    
    void toString() {
        Node *temp = header;
        
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);
    list.toString();
    return 0;
}
```

But the program is giving bad access after reaching the last node while printing the list. What is the problem with this code? Can anyone please explain on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append()` is not initializing the `n->next` member to NULL. You should do that initialization in `Node`'s constructor, eg:

```cpp
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int data) {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL; // <-- add this!
    }
};
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next = nullptr;
    
    Node(int data) : data(data) {}
};
```

Or:

```cpp
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int data, Node *next = nullptr) : data(data), next(next) {}
};
```

---

That being said, your `LinkedList` is leaking nodes.  You need to add a destructor to free the nodes.  You should also add a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). And in C++11 and later, add a move constructor and a move assignment operator, per the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Try this:

```cpp
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int data, Node *next = nullptr) : data(data), next(next) {}
};


class LinkedList {
private:
    Node *header = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
    
public:
    LinkedList() = default;
    
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &src) : LinkedList() {
        Node *temp = src.header;
        while (temp) {
            append(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    LinkedList(LinkedList &&src) : LinkedList() {
        std::swap(header, src.header);
        std::swap(tail, src.tail);
        std::swap(size, src.size);
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        Node *temp = header;
        while (temp) {
            Node *n = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = n;
        }
    }

    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList src) {
        std::swap(header, src.header);
        std::swap(tail, src.tail);
        std::swap(size, src.size);
        return *this;
    }

    int getSize() const {
        return size;
    }
    
    void append(int data) {
        Node **temp = (tail) ? &(tail->next) : &header;
        *temp = new Node(data);
        tail = *temp;
        ++size;
    }
    
    void prepend(int data) {
        header = new Node(data, header);
        if (!tail) tail = header;
        ++size;
    }
    
    void toString() const {
        Node *temp = header;
        while (temp) {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);
    list.toString();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always initialize the members of your class.

```
Node(int data)
: data(data)
, next(nullptr)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to assign `n->next` in `append()`. I suggest that you add an argument to your `Node` constructor to not forget that:

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;

    // make the constructor initialize both "data" and "next"
    Node(int data, Node* next) : 
        data(data), 
        next(next) 
    {}
};
```

With that, your `append()` and `prepend()` functions would have to supply the `next` node upon construction, making mistakes like this a little harder:

```
void append(int data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data, nullptr);
    
    if (header == nullptr) header = n;
    else                   tail->next = n;            
    
    tail = n;
    
    ++size;
}

void prepend(int data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data, header);
    
    if (header == nullptr) tail = n;
    header = n;
    
    ++size;
}
```

You also need to add a destructor to `delete` all the nodes to not leak memory.